# Create dynamically button with text from json

Tags: json, database, xamarin.android

I have connection with database by json url. I would like to add as many buttons as are objects in database. All I have to do dynamically. I can't find any resolution how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button for each entry, all you have to do is a request to get all your entries, then deserialize the JSON output into a class of your object that you need to create in your project. For example, let's admit your entry in database is a single varchar. You do your request like "SELECT * FROM table", get the json and deserialize in a class like Entry.cs that you made, containing :

```
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Then, using foreach statements and a List named, for example, entries, you get all your result as a collection. Then, with this list, you do a simple foreach where you create a button :

```
foreach (Entry entry in entries) {
    Button button = new Button(this)
    button.SetText(entry.Text);
    //Other button customizations, layoutparameters, etc
    view.AddView(button); /*Where view is the parent element where you want your buttons
    to be. Of course, you'll need a reference to it using FindViewById. It
    can be a linear layout for example, so all your buttons will align.
}
```

And that should be it. Note that if you have a lot of entries in your database, there might be a lot of buttons, so consider using a ScrollView.